# Jquery loop checkboxes with same name but different indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of checkboxes and the all have the same name but different keys:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="label-featured" name="labels[featured]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="label-new" name="labels[new]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="label-old" name="labels[old]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="label-promo" name="labels[promo]" value="1">
```

Changing the html and targeting a wrapper object are not options. Is there a way to select them as a group and loop them?

Comment: What do you mean with keys? They don't seem to have the same name either.

Comment: Are you just looking for [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select and loop like this:

```js
$("input[name^='labels']").each(function(index) {
  console.log(index + ": " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="label-featured" name="labels[featured]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="label-new" name="labels[new]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="label-old" name="labels[old]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="label-promo" name="labels[promo]" value="1">
```

The `"input[name^='labels']"` selector will grab all `<input>` elements that have a name that starts with `labels` (since `^=` means "starts with").

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could help. Please approve the answer to confirm that this worked for you.